Domino web form...using javascript .js file resource in a script tag
In traditional Domino web application.   I added a file resource in Resources that is named 'msg.js'.   It includes one function:
function testRef() {
  alert('this works');
}

I need to call this function from a button on the Domino form in a browser.   The code behind the button is simply:
testRef()

The problem is gettng the file resource to actually be included.   I am not quite sure of the proper syntax, whether relative (preferred) path or not.  I have tried the following:
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Resources/Files/msg.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Files/msg.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/msg.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="msg.js"></script>

None of these work.   What am I doing wrong?   I have searched all over the web for tutorials on using file resources such as this and have yet to find the example that matches my scenario.
FYI I need this because I am using an opensource library that uses more modern javascript syntax than my Domino Designer supports so it will not let me save it directly in Script Libraries, for instance.

where is your js file located relative to the html?

it is imported into the Resoures/Files structual location that Domino Designer provides for images/files/etc.   It is not just sitting in a file folder on the server, at least that's not where I put it.   This Designer client is an implementation of Eclipse for working on the application, and it has everything broken down: forms, subforms, agents, views, etc....and in that structure there is Resources, of which sub-sections are there for: \Images, \Files,\Applets, \Style Sheets, and \Themes.

Ideally, don't put your javascript file under Resources/Files. This can cause some problems, though there are workarounds which I'll describe at the end of this answer.
Instead create a new javascript library under Code/Script Libraries, and copy the content of your javascript file into that.
If it's created under Code/Script Libraries, then you can do this in the Form design:

Select the "HTML Head Content" section of the form.
In the code pane, right-click, then click "Insert Resource".
Select your javascript library, then click OK.

If you do the above, then the Domino server will generate the correct path to the javascript file when it renders the HTML for the web browser.
There is a situation when you can't use the above method: Domino Designer's javascript editor has outdated validation rules, and it doesn't accept some newer javascript syntax. If you want or need to use javascript syntax which isn't allowed in a javascript library, then you should add your javascript under Resources/Files.
If your javascript is under Resources/Files, then you need to look at the Web Properties of the file and set its MIME Type to "text/javascript". If you don't set the MIME Type, many browsers won't load it.
With the MIME Type correctly set, this script tag should work when opening the form (i.e. the URL contains something like "FormName?OpenForm") in a web browser: <script type="text/javascript" src="msg.js"></script>
The above script tag won't work when opening a document created with the form. From a document, you either need the following relative tag: <script type="text/javascript" src="../msg.js"></script>
... Or a tag with an absolute URL which contains the database path relative to the Domino server's data directory.
You can't use "/Resources/Files" in a URL pointing to a file which appears under Resources/Files in a database. Neither "Resources" or "Files" exist as actual directories on the server. They're just categories in the Domino Designer UI.

URL commands for accessing DominoObjects use the following syntax: http://Host/Database/DominoObject?Action&Arguments where Database = the database in which the DominoObject resides (the .nsf file).
DominoObject = a Domino construct (for example, a database, view, document, form, navigator, agent, and so on).
"/Resources/Files/msg.js" would reference a js file in either
a) a folder of the Domino Data dir., named "Resources/Files"
b) a Domino DB called "Resources" without the usual ".nsf" extension.
See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2005079/absolute-vs-relative-urls
